# Array in an object passed by reference is empty, even though it was filled later on

Tags: php

In the progress of writing a little framework for a web app I came along some difficulties in making classes communicate with each other.

### Environment

I have an abstract class called *LizardModule*, that should be extended by all the single modules of the web-app. This class has a `final protected function registerController(...)`, that creates a new Object of the type `LizardController`. This is, as it sounds, based on the idea of MVC. With the `final protected function registerFunction(...)`, modules can register  functions for every controller. Those are stored using `addFunction(...)` on the controller object. Here is what this looks like:

**Example Module:**

```
class ModuleOverview extends LizardModule {
    protected function setup() {
        $this->registerController(
            'overview',
            'App Overview'
        );
        $this->registerFunction(
            'overview',
            'myfunction',
            'My Function',
            array(&$this, 'theFunctionToCall')
        );
    }

    public function theFunctionToCall() { ... Generate Content ... }
}
```

**Module Class:**

```
class LizardModule {
    private $controllers = array();

    final public function __construct() { $this->setup(); }

    abstract protected function setup();

    [...]

    final protected function registerController($controllerSlug, $controllerName) {
        if (array_key_exists($controllerSlug, $this->controllers))
            return false;

        $this->controllers[$controllerSlug] = new LizardController($controllerSlug, $controllerName);
    }

    final protected function registerFunction($controllerSlug, $functionSlug, $functionName, callable $function) {
        if (!array_key_exists($controllerSlug, $this->controllers))
            return false;

        $this->controllers[$controllerSlug]->addFunction($functionSlug, $functionName, $function);
    }
}
```

This results in a lot of objects of type LizardController in different places of the app. To make all of those objects accessable, I created a singleton class *LizardRouter*, that should hold a reference to all of those controller objects. Therefore, the controller-object registers itself with this singleton class:

**Controller Class:**

```
class LizardController {
    [...]
    private $functions = array();

    public function __construct($slug, $name, $menu) {
        $this->slug = $slug;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->menu = $menu;

        LizardRouter::registerController($this);
    }

    public function addFunction(...) { Tested, this works. }

    public function getFunctions() {
        return $this->functions;
    }
}
```

**Router Class:**

```
final class LizardRouter {
    [...]

    public static function getControllers() {
        return static::getInstance()->controllers;
    }

    public static function registerController(LizardController $controller) {
        static::getInstance()->controllers[] = $controller;
    }
}
```

### The Problem

The whole thing works alright for the controllers. In my interface class, I can read out all controllers and print a menu containing their names. The problem is: Whenever I access the controllers functions-array (see controller class) through the controllers-array given by the routing class, I get an empty array. I asume that somewhere a reference is not working and I am passing the actual controller object, before my module-class was able to add the functions to the controllers functions-array. But I can't figure out where exactly the problem lies. Here is an example from my interface class showing the problem:

```
foreach (LizardRouter::getControllers() as $controller) {

    // Allways returns an empty array, even though
    // the module added functions to the controller.
    $controller->getFunctions();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a very specific case, I guess it is unlikely, that anyone will ever stumble upon the same problem. Anyway; I found the reason for the problem:

Objects are by default passed as reference since PHP5. Variables are by default passed by value.

Arrays are handled like variables, so when I pass an array containing object-references, a new copy of this array is created and passed. Object references added to the array after it was passed are therefore only added to the original array.

**The solution** i chose was to create my own "array-class" for holding objects. It has nothing more than a private array object, a setter and a getter. Since this custom array class is an object, it is automatically passed by reference. Later I also added some functions to conveniently access the array - a good side-effect.